# ¿Cómo doy formato de hipervínculo a una etiqueta <a> que está dentro de un txt con Flask?

Tags: html, python, flask

Quiero conseguir recoger el contenido de un .txt y mostrarlo en un div. La primera parte, la de que se vea y lo formatee para que tenga en cuenta las tildes y todo lo tengo bien, el problema empieza cuando **en el txt tengo una etiqueta de hipervínculo() y no encuentro la manera de hacer que la etiqueta no se convierta en texto plano y que el navegador lo interprete como lo que es**. Os paso el código:

```
def leer_texto(nombre_archivo = "presentacion"):
    try:
        url_archivo = "static\content\\" + nombre_archivo + ".txt"
        print( url_archivo)
        with open(url_archivo, "r", encoding="utf-8") as archivo_abierto:
            texto = archivo_abierto.read()
        return texto
    
    except FileExistsError:
        return "No existe texto que mostrar"
def index():
    try:
        # Cargamos la imagen aleatoria elegida
        logo_src = cargar_imagen_aleatoria()
        if logo_src == 400:
            return lanzar_error()
    
        # Cargamos las imagenes estáticas, actualmente solo hay una imagen,
        # pero en caso de ampliarlo en el futuro, se cargarán en este bloque
        # Se ha dejado creado cargar_imagen.
        """
            GENERAMOS LOS TEXTOS
            Usando la función leer_texto, recogemos texto escrito en unos txt y lo leemos para pasárselo al HTML y darle más contenido.
        """
        texto_presentacion = leer_texto()
        texto_habilidades = leer_texto("habilidades")

        # Cargamos los proyectos de mi Github
        consulta_github = requests.get(
            url="https://api.github.com/users/schacon/repos", timeout=5
        )
        file = open(file="textoPrueba.json", mode="w", encoding="utf-8")
        file.write(consulta_github.text)

        # Se envía la página web final
        return render_template(
            "index.html",
            logotipo=logo_src,
            presentacion=texto_presentacion,
            habilidades=texto_habilidades,
        )
    except:
        return lanzar_error()
```

Documento .txt:

```
Programador nacido en 1994 y que descubrí la programación como hobby y, años después, como trabajo. Me he ido especializando en la parte Backend y desarrollo de software desde hace 5 años, utilizando JAVA( Swing y Springboot), Python( Flask, Django) y .Net. Con futuros pequeños proyectos que podéis encontrar en la sección de <a href = "">proyectos</a> o mirar mi <a href="https://github.com/HombreConNombre">github</a>.
```

Resultado que me sale:
[image: Resultado dado]

Igual estoy dando demasiadas vueltas, pero es más que nada para aprender y con la documentación no he encontrado solución.

¡Muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: Buenas! Podrías agregar un ejemplo del archivo `.txt` en cuestión? No termino de entender el problema. Te recomiendo también agregar un [example]. Saludos!

Comment: El problema que sea que tengas, no está en la función que publicas. Esta simplemente devuelve el texto del fichero. Nada que hacer allí.

Comment: Vale, actualizo el post con más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo primero, gracias por todo. Lo acabo de resolver, os comento qué hay que hacer:

En el html, cuando declaras el nombre de variable, hay que color |safe . Os pongo ejemplo:

```
 <section class = "cuerpo">
        <article>
        {{presentacion|safe}} 
        </article>
        <article>
        {{habilidades|safe}}
        </article>
    </section>
```

Os paso la url de la documentación de [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/)

Vuelvo a agradecer el interés.